# Android: Get number of lines of a text file in raw folder

Tags: java, android

Good day! I've been trying create a function that will return the number of lines in a text file located at raw folder but I always seem to get 0.

Heres the function I am using:

```
int getFileSize (InputStreamReader p_is) { 
        int lineCtr = 0;
        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(p_is);

            String theLine="";
            lineCtr = 0;
            while ((theLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {
                lineCtr++;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return lineCtr;

    }
```

Then I pass variable size to another activity:

```
    InputStreamReader is = new InputStreamReader(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.sampleTxt));          
    int size = getFileSize(InputStreamReader is);

    intent.putExtra("v_size", size);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Then I retrieve it in the other activity:

```
    fileSize = getIntent().getIntExtra("v_size",0);
```

When I try to show the fileSize, it always shows 0:

```
    message= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_message);

    String strSize = Integer.toString(fileSize);
    message.setText(strSize);
```

I have tried passing a string in putExtra() but it also shows 0. Please correct any mistakes you see and thank you for the help.

Comment: This is where you use a debugger. is lineCtr 0 always 0? is size always 0?

Comment: What is the purpose of this, as the raw content is static?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but don't forget to close the `Reader` or you may leak resources.

Comment: ummm, why do you have `int size = getFileSize(InputStreamReader is);`? It should be without `InputStreamReader`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's your line

```
int size = getFileSize(InputStreamReader is);
```

It doesn't need that `InputStreamReader` in there, that should show error when compiling code. Not sure how you managed to run it.

So you just have to remove that and then it should be able to read lines and the count you wanted.

Or is this `getFileSize(InputStreamReader is)` just a copy/paste error when you were writing your code to here?

Comment: +1 Continuing the discussion here. Not sure it was a "real" problem. To me it looked more like a homework. See how he did not give any feedback. However I think you have the correct answer. Are you sure it'll not compile. Seems to me he'll more have a warning saying something like "value never used".

Comment: Well when i try to create method and do the similar thing the Eclipse says: `Syntax error on token "...", delete this token`. But that's just my case so who knows.

Comment: And I think there is no way you can pass parameter like that.

Comment: Looks like this guy just asks a question and never comes back to mark the answer or even discuss of his problem.

Comment: As I said, for me it looks more like a homework and not a real problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code:

```
public static int countLine(String s){
    int ct=0;
    for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++){
        if(s.charAt(i)=='\n')
            ct++;
    }
    return ct;
}
```

String s is result of reading text file, I tried this code, and it worked correctly